# Conditional `if` statement with strings in shell script to configure two computers differently (Ubuntu/Gnome vs Debian/XCFE)

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements, command-substitution

I want to check the current distro in `.profile` because I have two computers. In one I have Ubuntu with Gnome, and in another I have Debian with XFCE. In either case I want to have different configurations, but I can't manage to even get the following code working in Ubuntu:

```
if [[ awk '{gsub(/ /, "", $1); print $1=$1}' /etc/issue == "Ubuntu" ]]; then
            gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''
            gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hot-keys false
fi
```

I get:

```
bash: .bashrc:223: conditional binary operator expected
bash: .bashrc:223: syntax error near `$1=$1}''
bash: .bashrc:223: `if [[ awk '{gsub(/ /, "", $1); print $1=$1}' /etc/issue == "Ubuntu" ]]; then'
```

But as far as I can tell, the conditional is rightly specified... Any clues any one?

Comment: Use `$(awk ...)`.

Comment: The things that go in a `[[ ]]` conditional expression are strings (including numeric strings) and operators, *not commands*. To use a command inside a `[[ ]]` expression, you'd generally use `$( )` to capture the command's output and use it as a string in the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to replace

```
if [[ awk '{gsub(/ /, "", $1); print $1=$1}' /etc/issue == "Ubuntu" ]]; then
```

with

```
source /etc/os-release
if [[ "$NAME" == "Ubuntu" ]]; then
```

Comment: One could also use `name=$(grep -Po '(?<=^NAME=).*(?=$)' "/etc/os-release")` or `name=$(grep -Po '(?<=^NAME=").*(?=")' "/etc/os-release")` (if double-quoted) for this.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much! And thank all the other contributors as every answer is a good tip. You're all wonderful! :)